# Is there a way to change access modifiers scope on a final method?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, access-modifiers

Is there a way to change access modifiers scope on a final method from children who inherited it without reimplement it?

Comment: What is the use-case?

Comment: An abstract class defines a protected final method. I want my child to expose that method in a private way, i.e, no exposing it

Comment: Your child class will still have that method as `protected`, which should make it invisible to most other code..?

Comment: Can you explain what you're _actually_ trying to do?  If you forced a subtype to implement a method as private, how would you actually use that method, and what would be the point?

Comment: Because I can have a final method on parent's that execute some internal methods which need to be implemented on child. MainPublicMethod() {doInternallyAFirst(); thenB();thenC()}. But I don't want them to be called outside the child, only MainPublicMethod(). Don't worry, if it's not possible I already deduce it's a bad design idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot override the final method in child class.Final key word is meant for stoping from overriding.

Comment: so i'll never be able to override it's access modifier ever

Comment: what you trying to achieve here